# Get caller method name in js inside prototype

Tags: javascript

I have method named **my** from where I am calling prototype .Inside prototype I want to get Method name from where I am calling . The code below gives all the code of function.

```js
var c = new Object();
c.hello = {}

c.hello.my = function(b) {
  var d = 1,
    c = 1;
  ap('#love').try()
}

x.prototype.try = function(h) {
  console.log(arguments.callee.caller);
}
```

Above program gives all the code present inside  **c.hello.my** . How can we get the name of function (i.e my). If possible object name as well like **c.hello.my*.

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: You can give your function a name: `c.hello.my = function my(b) {`

Comment: Both `.callee` and `.caller` are deprecated and will not work in modern strict mode code.

Comment: What is `ap` and what is `x`?

Answer (score 1):

This has been deprecated to heck and back for both performance and security reasons. `Arguments.caller` is already non-functional on most engines, and this works at all because it's ultimately calling `function.caller`, and because you're not in strict mode. This will not work in modules, inside class definitions, and any distance into the future.

I have before been in situations where I thought it would be nice to distinguish who called a function, but I eventually work around it or let it go. If you need the reference to the CURRENT function expression, you can always give it a name:

```
...
c.hello.my = function NAME_GOES_HERE(b) {
  var d = 1,
    c = 1;
  ap('#love').try()
}
...
```

When you give a name this way to a function expression ('x=function F()'), the name might or might not be referenced as a variable outside the function, but it's guaranteed to be usable and valid from inside the function.

If a function has a name, you can read `function.name` to see it. Bear in mind that the textual name isn't nearly as useful in Javascript as it is in other languages. If you want this for debugging purposes, I suggest looking at [error.stack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack). This is non-standard, but has very similar output across browsers.